# Отношения в django

Tags: django

Как реализовать отношения в `django`? Нужна возможность добавления в друзья, желательно с запросами на добавление. Есть ли готовое решение с хорошим описанием или придется писать и мучиться самому?

Comment: С соседкой?

Comment: Социалку пишешь? Проходили такое, готовых решений не видел, боюсь придется помучиться хорошенько..

Comment: @breaf Да, а [`Pinax`][1] и [`vikuit`][2] - это хрень какая-то.

[1]: http://pinaxproject.com/
[2]: http://www.vikuit.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, самому написать...